# Compile user mode driver in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

There is a driver project https://github.com/Psypher9/VG-STC-Driver/tree/master/WinVgStc .

I want to compile it.

I have:

1. Windows 10 19041.1
2. Visual Studio 2013 Community 12.0.40629.0
3. From this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk installed:
4. Refreshed Windows SDK 10.0.19041.16385 for Windows 10, version 2004
5. Refreshed WDK for Windows 10, version 2004

Issue:

Trying to build, get errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: WinVgStc, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  Device.c
1>c:\users\usr\downloads\winvgstc\winvgstc\driver.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wdf.h': No such file or directory
1>  Driver.c
1>c:\users\usr\downloads\winvgstc\winvgstc\driver.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wdf.h': No such file or directory
1>  Queue.c
1>c:\users\usr\downloads\winvgstc\winvgstc\driver.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wdf.h': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I downloaded this project from GitHub the first error was, that there is no usermode drivers toolset. In project properties I changed it to `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)`. Then I got the error list above.

At this point I didn't have SDK and WDK I mentioned in the list above, so I downloaded it.

After restarting Visual Studio I still have errors. Also there is still only 2 variants of platform toolset in project properties: `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)` and `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`.

What should I do to compile it on the current Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe,after installation I should set new sdk or wdk path in project properties?

Comment: It's been a while since I built any new drivers but, from what I remember, it's normal to open up a command prompt into an specific environment and build from there. You can do it from the IDE, but you'll have to set all sorts of configurations and library/header paths.

Comment: @AdrianMole but what is the sense of doing it? To get errors not in IDE, but in console window?

Comment: Like I said, it's been a while. But there used to be batch files that set up a command prompt that already had the required configurations defined. So, once in that command 'window', all the header and library locations were set up correctly.

Comment: As you seem to have installed the WDK, then maybe there is just such a command prompt shortcut, somewhere in your Start Menu. The WDK used to do that.

Comment: @AdrianMole, have idea how it should be called?